# How to add padding/margin for sidebar-right in Adaptive Theme?

Tags: theming

I am trying to make something with Adaptive Theme, but I can't find how to set a padding or margin to Right Sidebar...

I am using only `content -- right sidebar`  layout, and if I wish to add some padding for Right Sidebar - it just disappears and falls down to bottom of page.....

Also, the problem started when I wanted to remove any Margin for a Content area, which was set to 10 px; but - when I removed margin for Content, it disappeared from Sidebar; and if I try to add margin/padding to Sidebar only, It just fall to bottom of page, probably resembling the tablet layout...

Comment: I suspect being that it's adaptive, it would have a maximum width set, if the elements exceed that maximum it shifts everything down. In order to increase the sidebar you would need to reduce the size of the content area, or increase the total maximum width allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Geoff said is basically true, but there is a way to change the margins and the paddings without messing up your basic page layout.

The way to do it is the following:

- Take a look at the structure of the HTML in the sidebar region. There should be a div that has a class .region-sidebar-second or .region-sidebar-first. If you try to change the padding/margin of this div, your structure will be messed up.
- You can, however, change the margin and padding of the div with the region-inner class by using a selector like ".region-sidebar-first .region-inner" or ".region-sidebar-second .region-inner".
- You can even go deeper if you want to change the margin/padding of a specific block and not the whole region's by using something like ".region-sidebar-second #blockID" as your css selector.

Comment: Thanks, .region-sidebar-second .region-inner is what I needed... I know I could add separately to each block, but it wouldn't be comfy always to remember to add...

Comment: You can mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem. This will give you higher acceptance rates and make it more likely for people to answer to your questions in the future (this also goes for all the questions that you have asked so far)